# .Net 5.0 Blazor problems on Raspberry PI does not show NavMenu

Tags: .net, blazor, raspberry-pi4

Having Issues with .Net 5.0 Blazor on Raspberry Pi (4) where Blazor Application does not show NavMenu when executing project on command line.  I did not have this problem when testing same application on .Net Core 3.1  or on Windows.

```
Having Issues with .Net 5.0 Blazor on Raspberry Pi (4)

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
  Executing endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
  Executed endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
  Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0 - 200 316 application/json 21.1461ms
 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
  Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff - -
 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
  Sending file. Request path: '/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff'. Physical path: 'C:\SRC\WpfCustomer\BlazorServer50\wwwroot\css\open-iconic\font\fonts\open-iconic.woff'
  info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
  Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff - - - 200 14984 application/font-woff 0.7443ms
  info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
  Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/_blazor?id=fFana5T4zEjS2og61Rm17A - -
   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
  Executing endpoint '/_blazor'
```

On Raspberry PI 4,  .Net 5.0 Blazor does not execute the following and also the does not show NavMenu.
But works fine on .Net 3.1

```
 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
  Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico - -
 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
  Sending file. Request path: '/favicon.ico'. Physical path: 'C:\SRC\WpfCustomer\BlazorServer50\wwwroot\favicon.ico'
  info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
  Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico - - - 200 5430 image/x-icon 0.6424ms
```

Also the following is executed

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
```

The following code is one I believe the issue is having and I believe when it is validating path

```
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!ValidateNoEndpoint(context))
        {
            _logger.EndpointMatched();
        }
        else if (!ValidateMethod(context))
        {
            _logger.RequestMethodNotSupported(context.Request.Method);
        }
        else if (!ValidatePath(context, _matchUrl, out var subPath))
        {
            _logger.PathMismatch(subPath);
        }
        else if (!LookupContentType(_contentTypeProvider, _options, subPath, out var contentType))
        {
            _logger.FileTypeNotSupported(subPath);
        }
        else
        {
            // If we get here, we can try to serve the file
            return TryServeStaticFile(context, contentType, subPath);
        }

        return _next(context);
    }
```

Just for information - I am using terminal and runing "dotnet run" in directory of project.  Keep in mind .Net 3.1 works this way

Comment: One additional thing,  I thought maybe it could be related to security issues with HTTPS and localhost - but that does not explained why .Net Core 3.1 version works fine.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm trying something similar and am getting issues